# Does every point in the Koch curve belong to one of its approximating polygons?

Tags: real-analysis, fractals, fractal-analysis

So, pretty self-explanatory title: I was wondering wether if every point that the Koch curve has does necesarilly belong to one of its approximating polygons. Just in case, on the picture below, the first approximating polygons are shown.

[image]

My intuition says "yes" because the Koch curve is not space-filling, but I do not really trust my intuition with this kind of questions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The points of an approximating polygon that will never be moved again form a nowhere dense subset of the polygon. The points from the first segment that don't get moved again are the Cantor set. The points from the other polygons are obtained by placing Cantor sets on each of the sides of the peaks added to the previous stage. Therefore, the set of points of the curve that belong to one of the polygons is a countable union of those nowhere dense sets. Therefore, by Baire's theorem it cannot be the whole curve.

Comment: @plop I am aware that the set of the "vertex" points of a polygon is nowhere dense and does not change, and if those were the only points of the polygon to never change, your argument would be correct, but why are you so sure that the set of never changing vertex is nowhere dense?

Comment: I didn't say that the vertices are the only points that don't change, nor used it in my argument. Fix any segment in any of the polygons and look at the intervals from it that get removed from it in all subsequent stages. Those are the same that get removed in the definition of the Cantor set. The proof that the Cantor set of nowhere dense is standard. Pick an arbitrary interval inside $[0,1]$ and show that eventually the construction tells you to remove an interval that is contained in the interval you chose.

Comment: OH! I have just read your edit. I do actually really like your argument. Very neat!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The $n$th approximating polygon (as you have drawn it) can be described in the obvious way by a function $f_n:[0,1]\to\Bbb R^2$. And then we can define the Koch curve by
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$$
The behaviour of $f_n(x)$ as $n\to\infty$ depends on the base-$4$ expansion of $x$. Specifically, $x$ belongs to an approximating polygon if and only if its base-$4$ expansion terminates.

So the set of points on the Koch curve which belong to an approximating polygon is countable.

Comment: I understand your argument and I actually like it because it shows that my intuition was wrong,  but I don't want to define the Koch curve as the image of the unit interval via the uniform limit of the squence $f_n$. I'd rather provide a locus to the Koch curve via the approximating polygons, then show that the limit of the sequence $f_n$ does actually parametrize the Koch curve.

Comment: Err...wut?${}{}$

Comment: I'll try to explain myself better: in the classical notion, the Koch curve (K) is defined by its locus as the limit of the approximating polygons ($K_n$) that the drawings suggest. If you are to proof that such curve is actually continuous, an strategy (the one I am following) is to provide a parametrization $f_n$ for $K_n$ and show that $f(I)=K$, for $f=\lim f_n$. The fact that $f$ is the uniform limit of $(f_n )$ does only guarantee $f(I)\subset K$. The question I've asked is an intermediate step to prove that $K\subset f(I)$

Comment: Also, I am aware that using the Hausdorf measure this would be like one line, but I want to keep it simple in tools.

Comment: Well, OK...if you want to do this with one hand tied behind your back, that is your prerogative.